# Using groupByKey to combine values for using with FPGrowth

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-mining

I have file of the form User, Item, which I'd like to use with [Spark Itemsets](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html). I've done this:

```
val data = sc.textFile("myfile")
             .map(line => (line.trim.split(' ')(0), line.trim.split(' ')(1)))
             .groupByKey()
val fpg = new FPGrowth().setMinSupport(0.2).setNumPartitions(10)
val model = fpg.run(data)
```

but it is complaining that

> inferred type arguments [Nothing,(String, Iterable[String])] do not
>   conform to method run's type parameter bounds [Item,Basket <:
>   Iterable[Item]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Basket` has to be `java.lang.Iterable` so neither `Tuple2` or Scala `Iterable` won't work here. Just drop keys and convert baskets to `Array` before you pass data to `run` method:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Seq("1 a", "1 b", "2 b", "2 c"))
  .map(_.split(" ") match {
    case Array(id, item, _*) => (id, item)
  })
  .groupByKey()
  .values  // Take only values
  .map(_.toArray)  // Convert to Array

val fpg = new FPGrowth().setMinSupport(0.2).setNumPartitions(10)
val model = fpg.run(data)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to avoid splitting the line twice in map?